# Not all SQS messages end up in Lambda: most just disappear

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an AWS SQS Queue (standard, non-FIFO) that has a Lambda function as a consumer.

Whenever I send a bunch of messages (usually around 10 at a time) to the queue, only about 2 get picked up by lambda (verified in CloudWatch Logs). The others disappear from the queue.

The Lambda batch size is set to 1, so I would expect all 10 messages to sit in the queue and get picked up by Lambda one by one, but that's not happening. I'm using CloudWatch to check what Lambda is doing, and there is no trace of the missing messages.

I verified in Lambda that it only gets one message every time, by logging the size of the `event.Records` array (which is always 1).

The Queue also has a **Dead Letter Queue**. Initially the **Maximum Receives** was set to 1. When I increased that to 3, more messages were getting picked up after the queues **Visibility timeout**, but still only a few.

**My Queue settings**

- Visibility timeout: 2 minutes
- Delivery delay: 0 seconds
- Receive message wait time: 5 seconds
- Message retention period: 4 days
- Maximum message size: 256kb

I'm wondering why the messages aren't being processed, but instead disappear?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) recommends: "To allow your function time to process each batch of records, **set the source queue's visibility timeout to at least 6 times the timeout that you configure on your function**. The extra time allows for Lambda to retry if your function execution is throttled while your function is processing a previous batch." What is the timeout set on the Lambda function? In CloudWatch Logs, are you seeing why messages are failing and being sent to the Dead Letter Queue?

Comment: The Lambda timeout is 90 seconds. So I guess I should set the visibility timeout to 9 minutes?

The weird thing is that the messages aren't failing in Lambda. I log whenever a message is picked up by lambda, and the messages that disappear do not show u p in the logs either.

Comment: Normally, the answer to this type of problem is that the Lambda function is not processing all the `event.Records` entries (a lot of people hard-code to only process the first message). However, that doesn't seem to be the situation in your case. You could try disconnecting the SQS queue as a trigger to the Lambda function, just to confirm that the messages accumulate in the queue correctly (and nothing else is consuming them).

Comment: I did that in my test queue, and when I shoot 10 messages to it, all 10 messages are showing up.

Comment: And when you connect a Lambda function to your test queue, does the function receive _all_ of the messages? Any chance you can try temporarily disconnecting the Lambda function from the non-test queue, to see if the messages all stay in the queue? Because something must be grabbing them!

Comment: Tried that, send 12 messages to the queue, and all 12 remained in the queue. So I'm pretty sure there's no other consumer.
I'm now making the consumer bite off more messages than 1, see if that helps.

Comment: I changed the Lambda script to let it consume multiple messages, and changed the batch size to 3. Now pretty much all messages get picked up.

Comment: Great! What do you mean by "pretty much all"? And what was wrong with your original logging of "the size of the event.Records array"?

Comment: About 90% Still some messages seem to disappear, or at least not get picked up by Lambda, even when there is capacity. The logging was correct. Earlier, the batch size was ste to 1 and I wanted to make sure Lambda actually got 1 message at the time (it did).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out this was related to the Reserved Concurrency of  the Lambda function. My concurrency was set to 1, which caused issues.

**My expectation**
SQS messages will remain in the queue until there's a Lambda function available to pick them up.

**In reality**
Messages that are not picked up by Lambda because the function is throttled, and after the Visibility Timeout are treated as failed message.

There's an excellent blog post about this issue: https://data.solita.fi/lessons-learned-from-combining-sqs-and-lambda-in-a-data-project/

Comment: I had the same expectation, and - surprise - we ran into problems. Last year AWS introduced maxConcurrency for Lambda triggers which seems to work as per the initial expectations: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-maximum-concurrency-of-aws-lambda-functions-when-using-amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source/

Answer (score 4):

The typical reason why messages are lost is that the Lambda function triggered by Amazon SQS is not correctly **processing all Records passed to the function**.

Make sure the code loops through all `Records` passed in the even parameter, since multiple messages can be provided in each Lambda invocation.

Comment: I'm doing that now. Initially however, I had the batch size of the Lambda function set to 1, so looping through records should not have been necessary.